# Need one regex for 2019-01-09T11:05:29.000Z

Tags: javascript, regex

I am bit new to regex.. so here to get any help from anybody

tried to make one as below, but unfortunately not working

```
((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be a regex? There are date libraries that handle parsing dates from a known (and in this case, well documented) format for you.

Comment: Maybe `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z` , but it won't validate the date though.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that your problem is in the sub sequence `(?:-|\\/)` remove one of the backslashes in both occurrences of that sequence and the RE passes your test date.

```
re = '((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))'
new RegExp (re).test ('2019-01-09T11:05:29.000Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex :

> [0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]{1}

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/jNf5Yn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:

```js
var regex = /[1-2]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(3[0-1]|[1-2]\d|0[1-9])T(0\d|1[0-2])(:[0-5]\d){2}.\d{3}Z/

console.log('2019-01-09T11:05:29.000Z',regex.test('2019-01-09T11:05:29.000Z'));
console.log('2019-01-9T11:05:29.000Z',regex.test('2019-01-9T11:05:29.000Z'));
```