# Getting datetime format with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to find such substring in my string:

```
2022-10-06T00:12:39Z
```

But can't find the proper way to construct my regex. Tried with something like:

```
([0-9]+)T([0-9:])Z
```

But obviously doesn't work.
The substrings are always in this format `YYYY-MM-DDTH:i:sZ`

Comment: You are not matching hyphens in the first character class, and you have to repeat the second character class `([0-9-]+)T([0-9:]+)Z`

Comment: This page has some answers to get the separate parts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54110152/need-one-regex-for-2019-01-09t110529-000z

Answer (score 0):

This Regex will allow you to detect a whole match

```
2022-10-06T00:12:39Z
```

as well as significant parts of the match: The date and the time in separate groups!

```
2022-10-06 

00:12:39
```

`(?:([^TZ]+)T([^TZ]+)Z)`